# Problems converting a Char to an Integer in C++

Tags: c++, string, char, atoi

I've been looking for this but the other answers confuse me.
I just want to convert a char to an integer in C++. I've read something about `atoi` function but
it does not work for me. Here's my code:

```
string WORD, word;

cout<<"PLEASE INPUT STRING: "<<endl;

getline(cin,WORD);

for(int i=0; i<WORD.length(); i++){

if(isdigit(WORD[i])){

 word = atoi(WORD[i]);  //Here is my problem.

}else{

    cout<<"NO DIGITS TO CONVERT."<<endl;

}//else

}//for i
```

BTW, I checked if the char is a digit first.

Comment: I think you should be clearer on what are the input and output you would like to have. (I'm asking for an example of input and output string you would like to have)

Comment: A character *is* an integer, although maybe not the integer you want.

Comment: "NO DIGITS TO CONVERT" - to *what* ? you code appears to be looking for digit characters `'0' .. '9'`,then tries to convert them to their integer values, but then stores them right back into a string (`word`). *What problem are you **really** trying to solve* ?

Comment: Evil coding standard:  more than one variable that only differs by case.  Example:  `string WORD, word;`  To reduce the injection of errors, coding standards say to have variable names that are differ by case insensitivity.

Comment: @WhozCraig Because I need to convert that to later do a sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

atoi takes a NUL terminaled string.  It doesn't work on a single character.

You could do something like this:

```
int number;
if(isdigit(WORD[i])){
     char tmp[2];
     tmp[0] = WORD[i];
     tmp[1] = '\0';
     number = atoi(tmp);  // Now you're working with a NUL terminated string!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If `WORD[i]` is a digit, you can use the expression `WORD[i] - '0'` to convert the digit to a decimal number.

```
string WORD;
int digit;

cout<<"PLEASE INPUT STRING: "<<endl;

getline(cin,WORD);

for(int i=0; i<WORD.length(); i++){
   if ( isdigit(WORD[i]) ){
      digit = WORD[i] - '0';
      cout << "The digit: " << digit << endl;
   } else {
      cout<<"NO DIGITS TO CONVERT."<<endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can solve it by :

```
digit =  WORD[i] - '0';
```

replace it by your wrong line .

and you can

adding :edited for cruelcore attention**

Comment: And that stores back into a `std::string word` *how* ?

Comment: I guess you could use the opposite of subtraction and add '0' to your digit.  Another suggestion is to use `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: `string& operator=` is applicable for argument `char`. just cast `WORD[i] - '0'` to char, like `word = (char)(WORD[i] - '0');`

Answer (score 1):

By answer by user4437691, with an addition. you can not set string to int using `=`, but you can set it to char, according to this reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/

So cast it to char.

word = (char) (WORD[i] - '0');